# Rails 4. How to assign existing Project to Client (where Client has_many Projects) using form and dropdown list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have Client model and Project model. My Client has_many :projects and Project belongs_to :client.

In client #show view I'd like to have a form when I can choose an existing project (with no client assigned yet) and assign it to this client.

I tried:

```
= simple_form_for @client, url: assign_new_project_client_path do |f|
  = f.input :project, collection: Project.without_client.map {|p| [p.name, p] }
  = f.submit 'Add project'
```

I created new action in clients controller:

```
def assign_new_project
  @client.projects << project
  @client.save
end
```

Unfortunately it seems that input in simple_form_for can only accept actual attributes for client object. Mistake I'm getting says:

```
undefined method `project' for #<Client:0x0000000524a9f0>
```

I'd like to pass the project to my assign_new_project action as a variable or one of the params. I'd be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use:

```
f.association :projects
```

More details here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Answer (score 0):

You should do in your view:

```
= simple_form_for @client, url: assign_new_project_client_path do |f|
  = f.association :projects,
                  :collection => Project.without_client,
                  :label_method => :name
  = f.submit 'Add project'
```

and in your controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def assign_new_project
    @client.projects.build(project_params)

    if @client.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Project assigned successfully'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def project_params
    params.require(:client).permit(
      # other client fields,
      :project_ids => []
    )
  end 
end
```

Be sure to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects` to your `Client` model.

Comment: Didn't you mean `client_params`? I did all you suggested (with `client_params`) instead of `project_params` and now I'm getting `unknown attribute: project_ids`.